# C callback function crash on object pascal

Tags: c++, delphi

I'm creating a C dll like below.

```
#ifdef TEST_EXPORTS
#define TEST_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TEST_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    /* fun accept an argument status_callback which is a function pointer*/
    TEST_API void fun(void(*status_callback)(int));
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

and fun is implemented as:

```
void fun(void(*status_callback)(int)) {
   status_callback(0);
}
```

When using this dll on object pascal with delphi xe like below I got a crash with an access violation at the address of the callback function

```
type
 TStatusCallBack = procedure( Value: Integer ); stdcall;
 T_fun = procedure(cb : TStatusCallback );

procedure BCallBack( Value: Integer ); stdcall;
begin
   BStatus := value;
end;

begin
 _fun(BCallBack);
end;
```

Instantiation code:

```
DLLHandle := LoadLibrary( ‘mylib.dll’ );
if (DLLHandle > HDLL_ERROR) then
begin
  _fun := T_fun(GetProcAddress( DLLHandle, 'fun');
end;
```

What is the issue? Since I'm a noobie to C any comments??

Comment: Does `TEST_API` denote `stdcall`, not `cdecl`?

Comment: @MBo No. The macro is visible in the code provided.

Comment: I'm creating this dll using Visual studio, I think the default calling convention is cdecl. So I even try with cdecl in pascal. Still not working. by the way, Im a noob in C, pascal.

Comment: This is C++ rather than C. You know that you should be using cdecl and yet you use stdcall. Why?

Comment: The second part of code is not written by me, but one who knows pascal. Thats why.

Comment: does not the fun function cause the GPF instead of the callback? comment out everithing in the fun function except the callback and try it again.

Comment: I've other functions on this dll which are working perfectly except this one with a function pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are missing important details. We can't see the implementation of `fun` on the C++ side, and we can't see how you declared `_fun` on the Delphi side.

However there is one error that we can see. The calling convention for the callback does not match. The C++ code defines the callback as `__cdecl`. You need to use `cdecl` to match on the Delphi side, and not `stdcall`.

Likewise I expect that your Delphi code gets the calling convention wrong for `_fun`. Again it should be `cdecl` but the error message suggests your declaration is actually `register`.

In summary, make the following changes to your Delphi code:

- Declare the callback function type as `cdecl`.
- Declare the function that implements the callback as `cdecl`.
- Declare the import of `fun` as `cdecl`.

---

Looking at your edit, your error checking for the return value of `LoadLibrary` is wrong. Error is indicated by the return value being zero. Compare for equality with zero to test for failure.

You also fail to check for errors when calling `GetProcAddress`. You need to handle the case where `nil` is returned. Again, that could lead to a runtime error with your code as written.

And the code in your edit shows that all my guesses were correct. The solution is as detailed in the bullet points above.

Comment: You show how you declared T_fun, but not how _fun is instantiated: as external declaration using "static" DLL linking, or using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress? If so, please show that. And do the calling conventions match what David said, i.e. __cdecl for all of them?

Comment: Yes. It's exactly as I predicted. Follow the recipe at the end of the answer.

Comment: @Rudy It's clearly LoadLibrary. Look at the two type declarations.

Comment: @David: yes, probably. But we don't see how (or if) OP actually loads them, then. If _fun is nil, it will crash too.

Comment: As I said, follow the recipe in my answer. The problem is precisely as I guessed.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. Do I need to explicitly make __cdecl anywhere in my C++ library?

Comment: No, you don't need to. That's the default calling convention. However, it's prudent to be explicit. Pick a calling convention and specify it everywhere explicitly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan One more clarification. Is it ok to use stdcall for exposing function but to use default cdecl for other functions which are used for implementation? Ex: TEST_API void __stdcall fun(void(__stdcall *status_callback)(int));. Because the requirement is a WINAPI libraray from my side.

Comment: You can use whatever calling convention you like so long as it matches on both sides. There's nothing that says that a Windows library should be stdcall. Perfectly reasonable to use cdecl or stdcall.